# Cesim translucid material image

Tags: cesiumjs

I think I mean "translucent"...

I'm trying to put a rectangle with an image material and control the translucency of the image so I can see the background behind it (like we do with ordinary layers).

This is my code:

```
var redRectangle = viewer.entities.add({
    name : 'Red translucent rectangle',
    rectangle : {
        coordinates : Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(-110.0, 20.0, -80.0, 25.0),
        material : new Cesium.ImageMaterialProperty({
            image : '../images/Cesium_Logo_Color.jpg',
            transparent: true,
            translucent : true,
            alpha: 0.2
        }),    

    }
});
```

I can't get it to work. I already tried every option inside `material` but with no results.

try it in [Sandcastle](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/index.html#c=bZLbasJAEIZfZclNIsSNCoVioxTsTcHSYkuvArImY9x2D2F2E9Hiu3dzqKe6F8nOzP/92dlJxZBUHLaAZEIUbMkMDC8l/WxygZ824Uwry7gC9HsPiUpU5SiEbAGpZSoX4NjWhIKy3HIwlGVZ8JMo4pZiEsiY+AvIiEWmjChTp3MOHe6HrfCYcOqOrVeqNWZcMQvGFboDHr9N16jlE+QIYIL+cDigg5CMmmf/vg3u6KAXnvykc0LOhDM76/hZshxeutIb6gLQ7oKzY9SL16K6F0qjZm+iFl/Oda6XMy000q8i98NLrmm7YOjaHrughFv17lpuCpgoNmxMBnR0yh96Yf06JdrdIVGHbkztTPZayw8dXE2olnihFxu7EzBt0UcuC42WlCgC16EFWYj62qNVmX6DpalpsDj6g+KMV4Rnk8S7+lESj6SCGeMq61KId76HxJvGkdNfYEIzN9r8tQIUbFdLNsPpvE1SSuPIhf8pq7VYMTxz/AU). My goal is to see a translucid logo.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Need to give a color to the image ( what?? ) and apply an alpha to it.

```
var redRectangle = viewer.entities.add({
    name : 'Red translucent rectangle',
    rectangle : {
        coordinates : Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(-110.0, 20.0, -80.0, 25.0),
        material : new Cesium.ImageMaterialProperty({
            image : '../images/Cesium_Logo_Color.jpg',
            color: Cesium.Color.WHITE.withAlpha(0.1)  <<<< ----- THIS MAKE IT TRANSLUCENT
        }),    

    }
});
```